# Pine Script V5 plotting daily timeframe open price on 5 min chart

Tags: timezone, pine-script, tradingview-api

I would like to plot the open price from daily timeframe on my 5 minute timeframe chart with the below codes. Turned out the open rice from previous day is plotted.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
o = request.security(syminfo.ticker, "D", open)
plot(o)
```

[image]

Comment: Use this : `o = request.security(syminfo.ticker, "D", open, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `security` for that. You can simply use the `time()` to see if it is a new day and store the `open` price in a `var` variable. This way, your script will be more efficient.

```
var float daily_open = na

is_new_day = ta.change(time("D"))
daily_open := is_new_day ? open : daily_open // Update the price when it is a new day, keep its value otherwise

plot(daily_open)
```

If you really want to use the `security()`, you should add `barmerge.lookahead_on`.

```
o = request.security(syminfo.ticker, "D", open, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```